# output is null in the console

Tags: java, arrays, user-input

it's showing null exception. what to do now?

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Quiz1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File f = new File("QuizMark.txt");
        try{
            Scanner s = new Scanner (f);
            QuizMark[] p = new QuizMark[10];
            while(s.hasNext()==true)

            {
                int c = s.nextInt();
                double d = s.nextInt();             
                for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
                p[i]= new QuizMark(c,d);
                System.out.println(p[i].getId());
                System.out.println(p[i].getScore());
                i++;
                }
            }
        }
                catch(Exception e){
                    System.out.println(e.getMessage()); 
                    }
    }

}
```

Comment: can you please help me showing my fault here? I'm not understanding what to do now.

Comment: Did you read the link I posted?

Comment: And show the exact error if you want help.

Comment: yes, but there are many kinds of answers. it's making me confused.

Comment: NullPointerExceptions are extremely important to understand. You'll run into them all the time during Java development. Make sure you understand how to fix them, which the link I posted goes over in great detail. And again, post the exact error.

Comment: the error is, i created a file and trying to read it. but when i want to read the file, it's showing "null" in the console.

Comment: You said it's a null exception.

Comment: I'm new in java programming. i thought it null exception. because when i catch(Exception e){
        //System.out.println(e.getMessage()); 
        } skip the print line, it's showing nothing in catch

Comment: And without seeing the exact data being read, it's impossible to say for sure.

Comment: can i send you my code?

Comment: You haven't imported QuizMark.java

Comment: If I understand correctly, there is **not** an exception, but you are seeing "null" when you display values of `p[i].getId()` and `p[i].getScore()`. As Carcigenicate suggested, please post the content of file QuizMark.txt and source code for class QuizMark.

Comment: In your `catch` clause: Don't use `System.out.println(e.getMessage());`, but instead use `e.printStackTrace();` to get the full exception stack trace. Add this info to your question to get better help.

Answer (score 0):

First of all your file must define a pattern of data saved in it like marks and id Separated by commas or hyphens underscores etc whatever you like to save pattern.Each next data should be on next line.Then read the text in proper manner as you saved in file.

Example QuizMarks.txt

```
01,96.5
02,78.9
03,65
04,89.7
```

Java Code

```
 int count = 0;
 String s[];
 String line="";
 QuizMark[] p = new QuizMark[10];

 BufferedReader br= new BufferedReader(new FileReader("QuizMark.txt"));

 while(line=br.readLine()!=null){

 s=line.split(",");//your data separated by symbol in file 

 //First Record with id and marks 

 int id =Interger.parseInt(s[0]); //conversion from string to int
 double marks = Double.parseDouble(s[1]); //conversion from string to double

 p[count]= new QuizMark(id,marks);
 count++;


 }
```

Comment: You can use FileReader Class but FileReader reads file as a whole text without noting next line,

Comment: Best approach is using BufferedReader for reading any type of file